# Enzymes, Chemical reactions pathways to make a system of differential equations

Tags: mathematical-modeling, biology, chemistry

> **Past Paper Question:**

Consider an enzyme $E$ with four binding sites at which a substrate $S$ can (reversibly) bind to form a complex $C_1$, $C_2$, $C_3$, $C_4$ (with $1$, $2$, $3$ or $4$ binding sites occupied respectively) and hence (irreversibly) produce a product $P$. One of the chemical reactions is therefore given by the pathway:
$$S+E \rightleftharpoons^{4k_1}_{k_-1} C_1 \rightarrow^{k_2}_{}P+E$$
Assuming there is no cooperativity with the binding substrate, but that the presence of
two bound substrates renders the third and fourth sites inaccessible, give the remaining
chemical reactions.

> **My Attempt:**
>
> Since the question says "no cooperativity" it wouldn't be something like this: 
>   $$C_1+S \rightleftharpoons^{2k'_1}_{2k'_-1} C_2 \rightarrow^{2k'_2}_{}P+C_1$$
>   $$C_2+S \rightleftharpoons^{k''_1}_{3k''_-1} C_3 \rightarrow^{3k''_2}_{}P+C_2$$
>   Since the question says "renders the third and fourth sites inaccessible" I'm thinking its more like a reaction with some modifier M:
>   $$E+M \rightleftharpoons^{k_3}_{k_-3} C_M$$
>   $$C_M+S \rightleftharpoons^{k'_1}_{k'_-1} C_{SM} \rightarrow^{k'_2}_{}C_M+P$$
>   $$C_1+M \rightleftharpoons^{k'_3}_{k'_-3} C_{SM}$$

**My Question:**

How do you use this to find the correct chemical reaction paths ways?